# How to find the database instance in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Does rails create database instance when the server starts. if yes how can we get the instance of the database.

How can i create the table from rails console.[image]

Comment: "How can i create the table from rails console" - in 99.99% of cases, you don't need to create a table from a rails console. Use migrations instead. If you know why you **need** to create a table in a console, you already know how to do it.

Comment: I wanted to know is rails create database instance when the server start.

Comment: No, rails does not create a database on the DB server when the server starts. If the database exists already, rails may create an in-memory ruby object (instance) describing the database/connection, but that's not what you mean here, looks like.

Comment: You have completely missunderstood that quote. What its  talking about is when for example a new developer joins a project then they should setup their own development/test database by running `rails db:schema:load` instead of by running all the migrations. Thats whats meant by "database instance" - and its created as a setup step and not from the console or when starting the server.

Answer (score 2):

Rails does not create the database instance when the server starts. The server *expects* that the database has already been created and migrated.

There is no method to get the "instance" of the database, since it is all dependent on how the database is configured, typically in `config/database.yml`.

If you're deploying a Rails application, part of that process necessarily includes:

1. Creating or obtaining credentials on an appropriate database server
2. Altering `config/database.yml` to have the credentials set for the deployment environment, such as `production`
3. Provisioning the database on the server (`CREATE DATABASE` or `rails db:create`)
4. Running the migrations (`rails db:migrate`)
5. Seeding the database, if applicable (`rails db:seed`)

The same steps apply if you're just working locally on a development copy, except you'll be working with `development` and `test` environments.

Comment: i was going through the articles of rails guide and i found that database instance. i am adding the screenshot for your reference.

Comment: This is an very good attempt at answering a non-sensical question. I mean what does "get the instance" even mean? Connect to the database? See a list of the databases? Access its data?

Comment: `db:schema:load` is, in more technical terms, "restoring from a snapshot". It's another way to boot-strap your database.